# Applying one label for each iteration of a barchart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, dplyr

With some assistance from the wonderfully helpful users on this site, I have this code. The goal was to create a bar graph of test scores for each year in school, "level" , to create a visual that allows students to see how their score compare to their classmates' scores without disclosing who scored what. The resulting graphs would contain only one student's name and student #xx for the other students in the class. The following code works on this sample of data but when I apply it to my full dataset of 43 observations I get the following error:

```
"Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: Column `n` must be length 43 (the number of rows) or one, not 42."
```

Additionally, I would like to add all of the percentages on top of each bar.

```
names <- c("Jackson", "Smith", "Johnson", "Richards", "Matthews", "Redmond", "Phillips")
scores <- c(.99, .65, .73, .89, .88, .92, .87)
level <- c(10,11,10,11,11,11,11)
grades <- cbind.data.frame(names, scores, level)
df <- 1:nrow(grades) %>% 
     purrr::map( ~grades) %>% 
     set_names(grades$names) %>% 
     bind_rows(.id = "ID") %>% 
     nest(-ID) %>%  
 mutate(level=map2(data,ID, ~.x %>% filter(names == .y) %>% select(level))) %>% 
 mutate(data=
       map2(data, ID, ~.x %>% 
              mutate(n=paste0("#", sample(seq_len(n()), size = n())),
                     names=ifelse(names == .y, as.character(names), n),
                     names=factor(names, levels = c(.y, sample(n, n())))))) %>%
 mutate(plots=map2(data,level, ~ggplot(data=.x,aes(x = names, y = scores, fill = scores))+ 
           geom_col() +
           ggtitle("test scores by level-  February 2018", subtitle = .y$level)
 )) 
library(cowplot)
plot_grid(df$plots[[1]], df$plots[[2]], df$plots[[3]],df$plots[[4]])
```

Comment: To add percentages on top of each bar, include `geom_text(aes(label=scores*100), vjust=-.3)` to your `ggplot` sequence.  (You can play around with `vjust` as needed).  As far as the mutate error, it's hard to help if the code you provide doesn't reproduce the error.

Comment: @andrew_reece using geom_text() produces an error "Error: geom_text requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y"

Comment: I copied the code you posted, and add the `geom_text()` line I provided between `geom_col()` and `ggtitle`.  It rendered the graphs without error.